# In excel - comparing column of items to same array

Tags: excel

I'm working in excel. 
I've got a column of numbers.
I want to compare this column to another column of numbers and find exact matches. Then show these matches in another column.

I've tried using MATCH but I cannot get one column to move through the numbers in it and the other to stay the same.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Use an absolute reference for the list you're checking against: `=MATCH(A2, $E$1:$E$500, 0)` When you drag the formula only the A2 will adjust: the other range will stay fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns are say A and B (and either both with or both without headers) please try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A:A,B:B,0)),"")
```

in the first row of data, copied down to suit. The result should be in the same order as ColumnA, so you might want to sort A.